# Sharepoint Online CORS to Provider Hosted Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

I've got a really strange problem with Sharepoint Provider-hosted Add-in configuration, but only on production site.

I've got a frontend deployed to SiteAssets/home.js which is working fine, and the backend is on the Azure AppService.
On the site collection i've got the Application (`_layouts/15/AppNewReg.aspx`) created and the `.app` package from visual studio installed to global app catalog + added to the site.
When i'm calling the appService with ClientId from older deployment everything is working just fine, but when i generate a new ClientId, ClientSecret all i got from the appservice is a CORS ERROR.
I need to create exact configuration from scratch, and remove the previous, so i cannot just stick with the old "Frontend APP A"

```
+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
|                     | AppReg A       | AppReg  B      |
+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
| AppService Code OLD | OK             | CORS Error     |
| AppService Code NEW | 500 Error      | CORS Error     |
+---------------------+----------------+----------------+
```

[image: Sharepoint DevTools Console Errors]

There is a also a CORS error in the console

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/intra/*layouts/15/AppRedirect.aspx?client_id=8c6c8d0f-28f7-4dfa-9ac0-b6bacc8be503&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.azurewebsites.net%2FFeedback%2FGetCountOfActiveTicketsForCurrentUser%3F%7BStandardTokens%7D%26IntraClient%3Df9e4fd3b-713c-47e0-8443-6c11b7abde84%26*%3D1607450676287%26SPHasRedirectedToSharePoint%3D1' (redirected from 'https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/Feedback/GetCountOfActiveTicketsForCurrentUser?IntraClient=f9e4fd3b-713c-47e0-8443-6c11b7abde84&SPHostUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fxxx.sharepoint.com%2Fsites%2Fintra&_=1607450676287') from origin 'https://xxx.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
> xxx.azurewebsites.net/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js:9536

Answer (score 1):

The solution found by comparing the tho HTTP Flows in the browser (using Teleriks Fiddler) was to enable cookies on the AppService O_O

> ```
> <httpCookies sameSite="None" requireSSL="true"/>
> <sessionState cookieSameSite="None" />
> ```

[image: Azure AppService COde Editor Web.confg]

[image: Fiddler Request difference]